# Is it possible to decompose a struct in c++20 into a template parameter list

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, c++20

I want to write a variadic "struct of vectors" container, which takes a struct, decomposes it's components and creates own std::vectors for each.

To be able to think further structs must be decomposable into it's members.
Is that even possible with c++20?

Comment: Please share the code that you would *like to write*, even if it doesn't compile. Even non-working code is often easier to understand than english text.

Comment: Consider using [magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, could you please explain in a few words how it works internally?

Comment: @Evg Magic! I didn't look into it too much. I think they have different implementations for C++14 and C++17; not sure how the first one works, but the second one uses structured bindings (of various sizes, probably code-generated). To choose the size of a structured binding to apply, they use SFINAE to determine how many arguments are needed to aggregate-init the struct.